# time limit on regular expression in format MM:SS:HH

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, format

I need to validate a user input for minutes, seconds, and hundredths in the format MM:SS:HH. However, user's input can not go over 10 minutes. I'm not sure how to limit that and still keep for example 01:01:01 valid.

/^[0-1][0-0]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/

This is the expression I had, but my example of 01:01:01 would not have worked.

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: Split on `:` and test each part.

Comment: Matt, yes I do have to use a regular expression to validate input.

Comment: Is `10:59:59` valid since it's still the tenth minute? or is max `10:00:00`?

Comment: ctwheels, 10:00:00, but excellent point, my regex would have validated the other input.

Comment: `^(?:0\d(?::[0-5]\d){2}|10:00:00)$`?

Comment: Yes, that worked Thank you so much!

Comment: @newDevNow99 I've converted my comments to an answer (with code)

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

I would definitely split the time string on `:` and then test each part. That's the simplest solution. Alternatively, you can do this relatively easily using regex.

---

### Code

#### Method 1 - No regex

```js
const str = ["00:00:00", "05:05:05", "10:00:00", "10:00:01", "10:59:59", "20:20:20"];

str.forEach(function(s) {
  var a = s.split(":").map(Number);
  if(a[0] < 10 || (a[0] === 10 && a[1] === 0 && a[2] === 0)) {
      console.log(`Valid: ${s}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Invalid: ${s}`);
  }
});
```

#### Method 2 - Regex

```js
const regex = /^(?:0\d(?::[0-5]\d){2}|10:00:00)$/;
const str = ["00:00:00", "05:05:05", "10:00:00", "10:00:01", "10:59:59", "20:20:20"];

str.forEach(function(s) {
  if(regex.exec(s) !== null) {
    console.log(`Valid: ${s}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Invalid: ${s}`);
  }
});
```

---

### Explanation

I'll only explain the regex in **Method 2** as the rest is fairly simple. If you need an explanation about any other parts, however, feel free to ask!

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:0\d(?::[0-5]\d){2}|10:00:00)` Match either of the following

  - `0\d(?::[0-5]\d){2}` Match the following

    - `0` Match this literally
    - `\d` Match any digit
    - `(?::[0-5]\d){2}` Match the following exactly twice

      - `:` Match this literally
      - `[0-5]` Match a number in the range between `0` and `5`
      - `\d` Match any digit
  - `10:00:00` Match this literally
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

`/(10:00:00|^0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$)/`

```
['10:00:01', '10:00:00', '09:59:59', '05:05:05']
    .forEach(t => console.log(t.match(/(10:00:00|^0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$)/)))
```

Comment: What happens with input '01:junk` ?

Comment: I was just giving an solution to the question. The original question already knows how to solve '01:junk'. But okay, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is close. Simply change your regex to:

```
/^(10:00:00|0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])$/
```